# Function implementation on two-number swap

Tags: c

Why doesn't this program compile with a warning message that "uninitialized pointers were used"? If I change `pTemp` to an `int` variable instead of an `int` pointer variable, is it okay? Please explain why.

```
void Swap(int *x, int *y) { 
    int *pTemp;  
    pTemp = x;
    x = y;
    y = pTemp;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre]. We have no idea what the types of `x` and `y` are (or how this particular code is used)

Comment: you need to swap content of `x` and `y` then you need to do this, ```int pTemp;  
 pTemp = *x;
 *x = *y;
 *y = pTemp;```

Comment: Which line of the shown source is in the _complete_ message?

Comment: Because there is no use of uninitialized pointers here. But the swap function is wrong anyway.

Comment: you code doesn't produce a "uninitialized pointers were used". It is wrong in the sense that it doesn't do what you want it to do, but the error you are reporting does not come from the code you posted. Please create a proper [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here would be a simple example of swap without using ptemp as pointer but as simple local int as it would be easier to think. Having c as an int variable is not more right or more wrong, it is just different. If u have a ptemp int, then u should work with the content of the variables, which means that u have to access the addess of &x using *x as i used inside the swap. If u worked with ptemp pointer then u should work by memory addresses which is overkill for this example I think.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Swap(int *x, int *y)
{ 
    int c;  
    c = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = c;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    int x = 3;
    int y = 5;
    Swap(&x,&y);
    printf("X: %d, Y: %d", x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As posted, the code swaps the values of the function arguments, which has no effect outside the function. You should instead dereference the pointers to swap the values they point to, which requires a `temp` variable with type `int`.

Here is a modified version:

```
void Swap(int *x, int *y) { 
    int temp;  
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change a pointer variable to a variable, the function loses the ability to swap two numbers

```
void Swap(int *c, int *d) { 
    int *temp;  
    temp = *c;
    *c = *d;
    *d = temp;
}
```